# How to keep only one attribute value when merging attributes by using FME

Tags: fme-form

I have merged attributes of 2 different datasets in one attribute field. The problem is that some features share exactly the same attributes! I want to keep only one attribute value of the features if they are duplicated. How can this be done in FME 2021?

What I have :

```
field 1:
attribute_A,attribute_B,attribute_C
attribute_D,attribute_D,attribute_E
attribute_F,attribute_F,attribute_F
```

What I want:

```
field 1:
attribute_A,attribute_B,attribute_C
attribute_D,attribute_E,
attribute_F
```

I tried "list builder" for field 1 and tried to "substring" but unfortunately didn't succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following three transformers:

- AttributeSplitter https://www.safe.com/transformers/attribute-splitter/
- ListDuplicateRemover https://www.safe.com/transformers/list-duplicate-remover/
- ListConcatenator https://www.safe.com/transformers/list-concatenator/

The following worked for me:
[image: Example]

Comment: Good one. It's not easy to remove an item from a list and the ListDuplicateRemover is sometimes hard to find.